# getting all sub class recursively

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am trying to get all children `MenuItems` with sub childrens until to end, but this code get only first level.

How can I convert this code to manage that functionality?

```
public class MenuItem : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
    public bool onMenu { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {
        Children = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}

IEnumerable<Entity.MenuItem> _menuItemList = _menuItemRepository.FindByIncluding(x => x.Parent == null && x.onMenu == true, t => t.Children);

public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindByIncluding(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        query = query.Where(predicate);
    }
    return query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recursion.

```
public List<MenuItem> GetItems (MenuItem item) {
    var items = item.Children;

    for (var i=0; i<item.Children.Count; i++) {
        var child = item.Children[i];
        items.AddRange(GetItems(child));
    }

    return items;
}

var allItems = GetItems(yourMainItem);
```

This will get all the children, the children's children and so on until you've retrieved them all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. You should get first level from FindByIncluding method, but the Children property should be also loaded.

If you want to return all MenuItems in one collection you should use something like this:

```
public class MenuItem : IEntityBase
{
    //Rest of your code goes here

    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetDescendants(bool includeItself = true)
    {
        if (includeItself)
        {
            yield return this;
        }

        foreach (MenuItem menuItem in this.Children)
        {
            foreach (MenuItem descendant in menuItem.GetDescendants(includeItself: true))
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get the all MenuItems in one collection by calling:

```
IEnumerable<Entity.MenuItem> _menuItemList = _menuItemRepository.FindByIncluding(x => x.Parent == null && x.onMenu == true, t => t.Children);
IEnumerable<Entity.MenuItem> _allItems = GetAllMenuItems(_menuItemList);

public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetAllMenuItems(IEnumerable<MenuItem> rootMenuItems)
{
    IEnumerable<MenuItem> result = rootMenuItems;

    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in rootMenuItems)
    {
        result = result.Concat(menuItem.GetDescendants(false))
    }

    return result;
}
```